# How to update phpmyadmin in centos 8?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have version 4.9.5, phpmyadmin says that the most recent stable version is 4.9.7 and visiting the phpmyadmin site I saw that version 5 was also released...

I found some tutorials to do it with ubuntu, but little or nothing with centos, and even with ubuntu I saw that some "tweaking" always needs to be done, and I access my phpmyadmin in a different directory than phpmyadmin, just to be safe (maybe just virtual host configuration).

And I'm not a super expert, for example I never know what to do with selinux ...

So, could someone explain the process, or maybe create a nice tutorial to upgrade phpmyadmin in centos 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is my process :

rename your phpmydmin folder to save it in case of a later problem you can come back to it

root : /usr/share/phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install php-mbstring php-zip php-gd

mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin
mkdir /etc/phpmyadmin
mkdir -p /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/phpmyadmin
touch /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup


// you can choose a version on their site
cd /tmp
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.0.2/phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-all-languages.tar.gz


tar xfz phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-all-languages.tar.gz
mv phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-all-languages/* /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
rm phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-all-languages.tar.gz
rm -rf phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-all-languages

// open your file
cp /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php  /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php


nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

In your file

You can use : https://www.pwdgen.org/ to generate blowfish_secret

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '32 characters'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

$cfg['TempDir'] = '/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp';
(close)


sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf


Configure your phpmyadmin file (see the documentation)
```